# Origem de "mal-assombrado"

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, origem

No Brasil, diferentemente de Portugal, usa-se "mal-assombrado" em vez de "assombrado", para se referir a um determinado objecto ou lugar considerado negativo, do ponto de vista espiritual. Por exemplo: casa mal-assombrada.

Parece suficiente dizer "casa assombrada". Quando e por qual razão se incorporou a partícula "mal" ao vocábulo?

Comment: Não sei se em Portugal não se diz também *mal-assombrado*. É um facto que podemos dizer simplesmente *casa assombrada*, mas quando vi o teu título, não me dei conta que fosse brasileirismo.

Comment: Bem, pelo menos, se não dizemos, já dissemos: «Mas o perro de Rui Pereira trá-lo decerto enfeitiçado.. e a todos. Parece que fez pacto de bruxo com Belzebu, e que tem novelo, o maldito! Senão, vede; de tantos navios que saíram aquando aos dele, olhai quantos ficaram em poder dos andaluzes! Só dos daquele ***mal-assombrado***.. nem um..» Arnaldo Gama (1828-69), *A Última Dona de São Nicolau*.

Comment: Alguém sabe dizer se actualmente ainda se utiliza **_mal-assombrado_**? É que, em Portugal, mais especificamente no Alentejo, fui intervindo com espanto quando a empreguei.

Comment: Eu nunca ouvi. O Priberam marca como brasileirismo.

Comment: Sim, dizemos "mal-assombrado" em pt-BR.  "casa mal-assombrada", "lugar mal-assombrado".  Mas se eu ouvisse "...é um lugar assombrado", também entenderia sem dificuldade.

Comment: Nunca o ouvi utilizado em linguagem corrente em Portugal, mas não me espantaria nada se fosse um maneirismo ou expressão popular utilizado para dar ênfase à frase.

Comment: Eu também nunca ouvi em Portugal, já tinha ouvido na ficção Brasileira.

Comment: No Brasil, usa-se tanto "assombrado" quanto "mal-assombrado", mas a última é preferível. Usamos "assombrado" como sinônimo de "espantado": "estou assombrado com a vitória do Trump", "a capacidade de recuperação do Real Madrid é assombrosa", "Joãozinho assombrou a todos quando tirou nota máxima em Matemática". Talvez por isso o "mal-" de "mal-assombrado"?

Comment: É que aqui no Brasil nem os fantasmas assombram com muito empenho e compromisso. /s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referindo-se a lugar onde se manifestam espíritos e espectros, ***mal assombrado*** parece ser a expressão mais antiga: aparece já no final do século XVIII, enquanto ***assombrado*** só consigo encontrar já no século XX. *Mal assombrado* parece ser exclusivamente brasileiro, e há a possibilidade de também *assombrado* ter surgido primeiro no Brasil e só depois passar a Portugal.

As duas expressões vêm de ***sombra***. Possivelmente por os cavalos se assustarem com sombras (Houaiss, Lisboa 2003), surgiu ***assombrar(-se)*** e, correspondentemente, ***assombrado*** com o significado de ‘assustado’, ‘aterrado’, nomeadamente, ‘aterrado como visões e aparições do demónio’, ‘sob a influência do demónio’, ‘molestado, atormentado’ (por algo mau). A nossa aceção de *assombrado* poderia facilmente vir daqui. Foi também daqui que veio o sentido ‘espantado, pasmado, maravilhado’ que *assombrado* mantém hoje [(Aulete 4)](http://www.aulete.com.br/assombrar)

Paralelamente surgiu ***bem assombrado*** e ***mal assombrado***. Um significava ‘bonito’, ‘com aspeto agradável’, ‘alegre’, ‘promissor’; o outro, o oposto: ‘feio’, ‘medonho’, ‘com mau aspeto’, ‘que inspira apreensão, medo’, ‘desgraçado’.

Parece-me que foi do cruzamento deste *mal assombrado* e de *assombrado* no sentido de ‘atormentado, molestado’ (por algo mau) que surgiu o *mal assombrado* no sentido de ‘frequentado por espíritos’ (passrei a referir-me a esta aceção por *o nosso mal assombrado*). Este sentido aparece explicitamente pela primeira vez no Google Books em 1789, no dicionário de Moraes Silva (MS 1789), no verbete *assombrado* (grafia original em todas as citações):

> § *Casas mal assombradas* , as que se dizem frequentadas de espiritos.

Quatro anos depois, o dicionário da Academia Real de Ciências de Lisboa de 1793 não inclui o nosso *mal assombrado*, mas a sua página e meia dedicada a tudo o que se relaciona com *sombra* e *assombrar* (é uma pena que não tenham passado da letra *A*), e repleta de citações literárias, ajudam a compreender melhor as aceções antecedentes (as citações literárias estão em letra normal; quase tudo o que é definição, em itálico):

> ASSOMBRAR […]
>   *Causar admiração ou pasmo* […]
>   *Atemorizar, intimidar, assustar, espantar com medo*[…]
>   *Vexar*. Do demonio , quando persegue as creaturas com visões e apparições […] Parece que o demonio , que o *assombrava* [hum boi] lho matou […] e pedirlhe o socorresse de modo , que o demonio perdesse de todo o ponto o poder , que tinha pera *assombrar* aquelle corpo.

De acordo com esta última aceção *vexar* (que de acordo com MS 1789, significava na época ‘perseguir’, ‘atormentar’, ‘molestar’), temos nos verbetes *assobrado* e *assombramento*:

> Assombrado do demonio, &c. *Vexado pelo espirito maligno* […] O menino parecia que era chêo e *assombrado do demonio* […] Huma moça *assombrada do espirito maligno*
>
> Assombramento abs. *ou* do demonio […] Padecer grandes *assombramentos do demonio* […] Huma mulher trouxe hum filho endemoninhado á capella do Santo… e ficou o filho livre do *assombramento*.

*Assombrado* significava também ‘afetado por’ (qualquer coisa má):

> ASSOMBRADO […]
>   Usase como adj. *Accommettido, assaltado, tocado de algum mal ou damno* […] Acabem já receios de mudanças, De cujo medo andei sempre *assombrado* […] coração *assombrado* de tristeza […]

Esta ideia aparece também no verbete *assombramento*

> Assombramento de ar. *Molestia procedida por alguma ligeira passagem do ar*. […]
>   Assombramento do coração. *Molestia , que opprime o coração*

Dentro do verbete *assombrado*, aparece ***bem*** e ***mal assombrado***:

> Bem *ou* mal assombrado. *De bom e agradavel aspecto e presença ou pelo contrário* […] Todos bem disposto , tanto homens como mulheres , de rosto alegre , *bem assombrados* […] O rosto era fêo , e *mal assombrado* […]
>   Seguelhe *em* ou *no* […] Foi de estatura meãa , mui *bem assombrado nos* olhos […]
>   *Que mostra ou denota alegria ou satisfação interior, ou pelo contrário.* […] Nunca mais  *bem assombrado*, nem mais alegre rosto lhe virão.
>   […]
>   Do ar , tempo , &c. […] O tempo da partida foi prospero , *bem assombrado* […] De nuvens tão escuras e *mal assombradas* tirou [Deus] raios fermosos de luzes resplendecentes.

Ainda sobre *bem* e *mal assombrado*, as passagens seguintes parecem pressagiar a nossa aceção de *mal assombrado*:

> Dos lugares […] E foise a hum ermo *mal assombrado* , e chêo de todos os temores […] E venho do lugar , para onde tu caminhas , e não he tão *bem assombrado* , que pareça saudável sem companhia.
>   Dos edifícios e artefactos […] Além de todas [as casas] por dentro serem melancolicas , escuras , e *mal assobradas* […] Ficou o Collegio em sua quantidade de mui boa fórma , airoso , e *bem assombrado*.

*Assombrar* significava também ‘fazer sombreados numa pintura’, equivalente ao atual [*sombrear* (Aulete 3)](http://www.aulete.com.br/sombrear). Não é claro se *bem* e *mal assombrado* vem deste significado, começando por ‘bonito’ e ‘feio’ e evoluindo para os outros sentidos; ou se *mal assombrado* veio de *assombrado* no sentido de ‘sob influência’ (de coisa má) e paralelamente surgiu *bem assombrado* com o significado de *sob influência de coisa boa*. De muitas passagens fica-se com a ideia que o pessoal da altura via muito da situação em que se encontravam como a influência de uma ‘sombra’ que podia ser boa ou má.

Seja como for não é nada difícil ver o nosso *mal assombrado*—‘frequentado por espíritos’—surgir destes outros sentidos de *mal assombrado* e *assombrado*. Ora o dicionário de Moraes Silva de 1789, onde o nosso *mal assombrado* primeiro aparece, foi publicado em Lisboa, mas o autor é natural do Rio de Janeiro. Excetuado as edições seguintes do MS, esta a expressão não volta a aparecer nos mais importantes dicionários publicados posteriormente em Portugal: nem no da Academia de 1793, nem no monumental *Thesouro da Lingua Portugueza* de 1871; também não a encontro na literatura portuguesa. Encontro-a no entanto na literatura brasileira a partir da segunda metade do século XIX. Tudo isto indica que a expressão é, desde a sua origem, exclusivamente brasileira. Eis um dos primeiros exemplos claros que encontrei (meu negrito em todas as citações):

> Aquele lugar tinha reputação de **mal-assombrado** […] Um, que por desgraça teve de passar por lá a desoras  [… c]ontou, que vira sobre a sepultura levantar-se um fantasma monstruoso […]
>   [(Bernardo Guimarães, *Histórias e Tradições da Província de Minas Gerais*, 1872.)](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/download/texto/bn000132.pdf)

Os dicionários de Cândido de Figueiredo, publicados em Portugal em 1899 e 1913, continuam a não ter o nosso *mal assombrado*. Segundo o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) o suplemento ad edição de 1899 tem no entanto ***assombração***. Eu não consegui encontrar esse suplemento, mas na edição de 1913, *assombração* já aparece no corpo principal, classificado como brasileirismo; nomeadamente, na aceção que mais nos interessa, como brasileirismo de São Paulo:

> **assombração** *f. Bras.* Susto, causado pelo encontro *ou* apparição de coisas sobrenaturaes; terror procedente de causa inexplicável. *Bras. de San-Paulo*. Apparição fantástica, que produz terror. (De *assombrar*)

***Assombrado***, com o nosso sentido preciso, só consegui encontrar a partir de 1940, quase o mesmo tempo em Portugal e no Brasil:

> O passado deixou ali tanto grito perdido, tanto cadáver insepulto, tanta alma penada […] E vá de inventar que havia um tesouro escondido naquele ermo de maldição. Encontrá-lo é que era difícil. Enterrado entre penedias, guardado por mil fantasmas, quem teria coragem de tentar a empresa? Ninguém. E o monte excomungado, lá continuava azulado na distância, agreste e **assombrado**.
>   [(Miguel Torga (Portugal, 1907-95), *Novos Contos da Montanha*, 1944.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=uEl_p20hAc4C&pg=PP3&dq=assombrado&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN-bGt7onQAhVHRhQKHWURCi44rAIQ6AEIczAM#v=onepage&q=assombrado&f=false)
>
> Quando reparou, ia passando pelo angicó, êsse que dizem que é **assombrado**. Correu um pouco, coração aos pulos, olhando para trás, a cada barulhinho. Ave, Maria, cheia de graça, meu Deus do céu, livrai-me de **assombração**
>   (Ruth Guimarães (Brasil, 1920-2014), *Água funda*, 1946.)

A partir de então, este assombrado encontra-se até ao presente quer em Portugal quer no Brasil; no Brasil, com menor frequência que *mal-assombrado*.

Entretanto, o meu dicionário Lello Universal de 1992 diz que esta aceção de *assombrado* é um brasileirismo. Este dicionário é claramente um edição muito anterior com acrescentos. Em 1992 *assombrado* não era um brasileirismo, mas é possível que umas décadas antes o fosse. Há portanto a possibilidade de também este *assombrado* ter tido origem no Brasil.

Não que em Portugal não existisse a ideia de lugares frequentados por espíritos. Por exemplo, [este artigo de 1844 na *Revista Universal Lisbonense*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9Q4XAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA570&dq=%22casa%20amaldi%C3%A7oada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO-r-ZtonQAhXCPRoKHaQ4D8kQ6AEIowIwJA#v=onepage&q=%22casa%20amaldi%C3%A7oada%22&f=false) fala de uma casa desabitada em Lisboa onde tinha havido crimes e «se ouvia ao bater da meia noite, uma restolhada seguida de uns gemidos , tudo muito sobrenatural». Simplesmente não lhe chamam nem *assombrada* nem *mal assombrada* (chamam-lhe *amaldiçoada*).

Para o surgimento de *assombrado* com o significado de *mal assombrado*, consigo imaginar duas vias possíveis. Uma, também possível em Portugal, seria apenas uma evolução dos antigos significados de *assombrado*, em especial o ‘atormentado pelo demónio’ e similares. A outra via, possível apenas no Brasil, é de *mal assombrado*. Esta expressão, com o nosso sentido, já vem do século XVIII. Depois de entrarem em uso, relacionados com este *mal assombrado*, *assombração* e *assombrar*, seria fácil algumas pessoas deixarem cair o *mal* de *mal assombrado*. Se assombrações assombram uma casa, seria natural dizer que a casa é simplesmente *assombrada*.

Comment: Acho este post de um qualidade extraordinária, caríssimo Jacinto. Atenção que "vexação" do latim "vexo" é palavra usada no contexto da demonologia cristã, o seu uso será anterior à própria língua Portuguesa. A literatura mística/monástica cátolica no séc.XVIII estava em voga, mas tenho dúvidas que permitissem desvios na terminologia por introdução de novos termos. O verbete no Moraes Silva sugere a palavra ter origem popular, porque as publicações à época passavam pela real mesa censória e pelo santo ofício. O artigo de 1844 é notório por ser posterior à extinção das ordens religiosas em 1834.

Comment: Repara que as outras palavras do MS1789: endemoinhado, amaldiçoado, vexado, perseguido, molestar são terminologia clássica da teologia directamente tirados do ritual romano (fonte primária para estes casos). Assombrado terá sido um termo vernacular que simplesmente começou a entrar em circulação.

Comment: @bad_coder, também me parece que *assombrar*, com todas a ramificações semânticas que foi tendo, foi criação vernácula.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade a diferença entre mal assombrado e assombrado quer dizer q mal assombrado e quando um espírito incompetente mal consegue assombrar já na assombrado quer dizer que o espírito assombra com êxito espero ter ajudado

Comment: Bem vindo ao SE em Português @RogerGR. Eu só quero deixar este reparo: Atribuir qualidades de incompetente a um "espírito", ou equacionar o bem/mal-assombrado à relativa eficâcia do mesmo, é questão de meta-física e portanto profundamente subjectivo. Acho, que a tua reposta merece esta ressalva: transcende o uso corrente da palavra "mal-assombrado" tal como é usada no dicionário ou no imaginário popular, e atribui-lhe um sentido específico que é particular e está para além do uso comum, ou da origem histórica do termo, que era a pergunta inícial.